# column and row names for a matrix?

Tags: r

```
data(mtcars)
corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)
```

I want to have the same output but applying this function:

So we can use

```
  matrix(apply(expand.grid(1:11,1:11),1, function(r)cor(mtcars[r[1]],mtcars[r[2]])),11)
```

which   is (almost) equivalent to cor(mtcars).

the thing here is that I need the output to be similar to mtcars i.e adding the column and row names, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add row and column names like this:

```
mat <- matrix(apply(expand.grid(1:11,1:11),1, function(r)cor(mtcars[r[1]],mtcars[r[2]])),11) 
rownames(mat) <- names(mtcars)
colnames(mat) <- names(mtcars)
```